# dplyr group_by() and summarise() to do calculations within groups between chosen rows

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

Using the `mpg` data to obtain a base example:

```
dat <- mpg %>% 
select(manufacturer, year, displ) %>% 
group_by(manufacturer, year) %>% 
summarise(meandispl = mean(displ)) %>% 
ungroup()

# A tibble: 30 x 3
# Groups:   manufacturer [15]
   manufacturer  year meandispl
   <chr>        <int>     <dbl>
 1 audi          1999      2.36
 2 audi          2008      2.73
 3 chevrolet     1999      4.97
 4 chevrolet     2008      5.12
 5 dodge         1999      4.32
 6 dodge         2008      4.42
 7 ford          1999      4.45
 8 ford          2008      4.66
 9 honda         1999      1.6 
10 honda         2008      1.85
```

With these data, I would like to `group_by` `manufacturer` and `summarize` to compare `meandispl` between `1999` and `2008` without using the row numbers (e.g. with `first` and `end` of `slice`)

So far for only one summarized variable (but there can be multiple), I came up with:

```
dat %>% 
group_by(manufacturer) %>%
summarise(diff2008_1999 = meandispl[which(year == 2008)] - meandispl[which(year == 1999)])
```

However, I feel this is not the tidy way to do. Is there other options to write this code? (without using the row number). In that case I used `year` but it could be a string as well (so no `min`, `max` solution)

Thank you.

Comment: Where does the `mpg` data set come from?? I can't replicate your example...

Comment: The `mpg` data is automatically loaded with `ggplot2` within the `tidyverse` package

Answer (score 0):

You could use `diff`

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% group_by(manufacturer) %>%  summarise(diff = diff(meandispl))
```

If there are other years as well, we can `filter` for specific years, `arrange` them and then `group_by` `manufacturer` and take `diff`.

```
dat %>% 
  filter(year %in% c(1999, 2008)) %>% 
  arrange(manufacturer, year) %>%
  group_by(manufacturer) %>%  
  summarise(diff = diff(meandispl))
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But in case I have all possible year between 1999 and 2008 I would like to be able to choose the year manually, eg 2000 and 2005

Comment: @tom you can include the interested year in the `filter` step `filter(year %in% c(2000, 2005))`

Comment: Thanks. The filter option is maybe not the best in my case, if I want to calculate multiple `diff`variables inside the `summarise` function: e.g. diff2000_2005, diff1999_2000. Sorry if my base example was too broad.

Comment: @tom A proper reproducible example which represents your actual data would be helpful but as far as I have understood from your comments till now you can try `dat %>% 
  filter(year %in% c(1999, 2000, 2005)) %>% 
  arrange(manufacturer, year) %>%
  group_by(manufacturer) %>%  
  summarise(diff = list(diff(meandispl))) %>%
  tidyr::unnest(diff)` Include all the years in `%in%` that you want.

Comment: Nope. I think you need to include a better example. I don't know why `diff2000_2005` and `diff1999_2000` are calculated.

Answer (score 0):

As Ronak Shah has already suggested, a better minimial reproducible example of the thing you want would make it easier to help you...

Anyways, here is another suggestion using `pivot_wider` to put each years values into their own columns

```
dat %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = year,
              values_from = meandispl,
              names_prefix = "year_") %>% 
  mutate(diff_2008_1999 = year_2008 - year_1999)
```